VBA to Sharepoint
Could someone help me please. I keep on getting this error

Error: Cannot update 'registration'; field not updateable.

Private Sub Test()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim table As String
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim vehicle As ClsVehicle
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    
    url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/"
    table = "934798bc-046e-4bb8-a608-913c86a5fdbd"
    With conn
        .connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                            "DATABASE=" & url & _
                            ";LIST={" & table & "};"
        .Open
    End With
    
    Set vehicle = New ClsVehicle
    With vehicle
        .setRegistration = "JS50LKGP"
        .setPalletsCapacity = 0
        .setTareWeight = 980
        .setOwnerId = 1
    End With
    
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" & table & "] (registration, pallets_capacity, tare_weight, owner_id) " & _
                       "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
        .CommandType = 1
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, 200, 1, 255, vehicle.getRegistration)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, 3, 1, 0, vehicle.getPalletsCapacity)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, 5, 1, 0, vehicle.getTareWeight)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, 3, 1, 0, vehicle.getOwnerId)

        .Execute
    End With
errHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description
End Sub


Error is triggered by which line exactly?  If you change the field order is it the same line?

Yes, even if i change the field order

Which code line though?  This one - .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, 200, 1, 255, vehicle.getRegistration) ?  Is there anything about the list configuration which would prevent that specific field being updated?

This line .Execute.
Even if i shuffle the fields, the error will be Cannot update 'which_ever_is_first_field'; field not updateable.

I'm assuming you have write access to the list?

You need IMEX=0 for writes, according to https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/#:~:text=Use%20different%20SharePoint%20list%20connections%20for%20read%20(IMEX%3D2)%20and%20writes%20(IMEX%3D0)%2C%20do%20not%20mix%20them.

It works IMEX=0 :)

You need IMEX=0 for writes, according to https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/#:~:text=Use%20different%20SharePoint%20list%20connections%20for%20read%20(IMEX%3D2)%20and%20writes%20(IMEX%3D0)%2C%20do%20not%20mix%20them
